# Why do both of the Parameterized Constructors for Detail throw Null Reference errors when setting the DetailNumber?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have code-first models. I am trying to get a detail to automatically set its own detail number from the constructor. Here is where I am so far:

```
public class Header
{
    public Header()
    {
        Details = new List<Detail>();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Detail> Details { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the Detail:

```
public class Detail
{

    public Detail(Guid id) : base()
    {
        HeaderId = id;
    }

    public Detail(Header header) : base()
    {
        Header = header;
    }

    private Detail()
    {
        DetailNumber = (Header.Details.Count) + 1;
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid HeaderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("HeaderId")]
    public virtual Header Header { get; set; }

    public int DetailNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ItemId")]
    public virtual InventoryItem Item { get; set; }
}
```

Why do both of the Parameterized Constructors for Detail throw Null Reference errors when setting the DetailNumber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this constructor

```
public Detail(Guid id) : base()
{
    HeaderId = id;
}
```

your Header is null because it is never initialized. And I think that on the second one the  `:base()` is executed before you parameterized constructor initializes Header.

You can rearrange your constructors a bit so that a `Header` will always be created if one is not passed in.

```
public Detail() : this(Guid.NewGuid())
{

}
public Detail(Guid id) : this(new Header())
{
    HeaderId = id;
}

public Detail(Header header) 
{
    Header = header;
    DetailNumber = (Header.Details.Count) + 1;
}
```